# The Product $AB$ can be Written as a Sum of Rank $1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

> Let $A$ be an $m \times n$ matrix and $B$ be a $n \times \ell$ matrix. Prove that $AB$  can be written as a sum of $n$ matrices of rank one.

I am having trouble seeing how this is true. Here is the best solution I could come up with. Let $A_p \in M_{m \times n}$ have its $p$-th column equal to $A$' $p$-th column, with zeros elsewhere, and let  $B_q$ be matrix whose $j$-th column is $B$'s $j$-th column, with zeros elsewhere. Clearly then $A = \sum A_p$ and $B = \sum B_q$. Then

$$AB = \sum_{p,q=1}^n A_p B_q$$

$$= \sum_{p=1}^n A_p B_p + \sum_{p \neq q}^n A_p B_q$$

I claim that $A_p B_q = 0$ if $p \neq q$. To see this, consider the $(i,j)$-th entry of $A_pB_q$:

$$(A_pB_q)_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^n (A_p)_{ik}(B_q)_{kj}$$

$$= (A_p)_{ip}(B_q)_{pj} + (A_p)_{iq}(B_q)_{qj} + \sum_{k \neq p,q}^n (A_p)_{ik}(B_q)_{kj}$$

Now, if neither $k=p$ nor $k=q$, then $(A_p)_{ik}=(B_q)_{kj}=0$, which means the sum on the LHS vanishes. When $k=p$, $(B_q)_{pj}=0$ since $B_q$ has zeros across every row, except possibly the $q$-th row; and a similar conclusion is drawn when $k=q$. Thus $(A_pB_q)_{ij}=0$.

---

As I was typing this up, I made a crucial mistake: I thought that the $p$-th column of  $A_pB_P$ was equal to $AB$ and had zeros elsewhere. I tried this on specific $3 \times 3$ $A$ and $B$ and found that every entry of $A_1B_1$ was nonzero; I did find that the $1$-st and $3$-rd column of my example were multiples of each other. So, it may be possible to fix this proof, but I cannot see it.

In any case, these matrices $A_pB_p$ are clearly not necessarily rank $1$ matrices. What I find disconcerting is that both [link1](https://jlch3554.files.wordpress.com/2012/11/la-solution-2011-7.pdf) and and [link2](http://www.ee.cooper.edu/~tam8/old/textbooks/Friedberg-solution-chap-1-4.pdf) give roughly the same answer (cf problem 18 on page 75 and 170, respectively), except they conclude that matrices in the sum are of rank at most $1$, which is the conclusion I am coming to draw. So, is this an error in the book.

Comment: Try multiplying column times row instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A = \sum_{p=1}^n A_p$ so $AB = \sum_{p=1}^n A_p B$, and $A_p B$ has rank $\le 1$ (hint: what do you know about the rank of a product of two matrices, in terms of the ranks of the two matrices?)

Comment: Not very much. I know that that $rank(XY) \le rank(X)$, whenever the product $XY$ is defined.

Comment: That's precisely what you need.

Comment: Oh!. So there is an error in the problem.

Comment: @ErickWong Because there seems to be no reason why $A_pB$ has to have rank $1$ rather than $0$.

Comment: @user193319 Ah, yes, the solution only establishes that the constituent matrices have rank $0$ or $1$.  It would not be unusual at all for a mathematician to use the term "rank-one matrix" to refer to a matrix of rank $\le 1$, but you are correct that this is a bit of a misnomer.

Answer (score 1):

For $n=1$ the claim is false when $AB = 0$.  For any other $n>1$, the claim may be salvaged as follows: if the constituent terms in the sum are all identically zero, then we can replace any pair with $\pm C$ where $C$ is a rank-one matrix of the appropriate size.  Thus WLOG we can assume at least one term $C$ is is non-zero, in which case we may replace it with $k$ copies of $C/k$ where $k$ is chosen to make the number of rank-1 terms exactly equal to $n$ (and drop the all the rank-0 summands).

But more likely, the author of the question just intended to use "of rank one" to mean "of rank $\le 1$", which is a very common usage that unfortunately is confusing here.